# LLVM backend module pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I would like to write a pass at the backend that goes over all the MachineBasicBlock in graph order and check if for each 3 consecutive MachineBasicBlock some property is achieved.

any Idea how to write this pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/09/16/analyzing-function-cfgs-with-llvm/) explains how to walk basic blocks in various graph orders (focusing on topological, but providing pointers for others as well). The same can be applied to `MachineBasicBlock`, using essentially the same mechanisms.

Comment: for backend pass that occurs after scheduling stage which file/class should I extend?

Comment: @user2660770: look at the other MI-level passes, where they register themselves